# JavaScript - How to filter the duplicate rows with another conditions apply

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, filter

I would like to filter duplicate rows with 1 condition

For example:

1) I have duplicate ID with different Status 
2) I want to filter the Duplicate IDs if the Status is 'Completed'

```
var data = [
    {ID : 1,
    Status : 'Completed'},
    {ID : 1,
    Status : 'Fail'},
    {ID : 2,
    Status : 'Fail'},
    {ID : 2,
    Status : 'Completed'},
    {ID : 3,
    Status : 'Fail'},
    {ID : 4,
    Status : 'Completed'},
    {ID : 5,
    Status : 'Completed'},
    ]
```

The result that I want :

```
var filter_data = [
    {ID : 1,
    Status : 'Fail'},
    {ID : 2,
    Status : 'Fail'},
    {ID : 3,
    Status : 'Fail'},
    {ID : 4,
    Status : 'Completed'},
    {ID : 5,
    Status : 'Completed'},
    ]
```

I want to try .filter() Anyone has any reference or example that I can refer to solve the question that I posted?

===========================================================================

I have another complex question need to solve **(Updated on 19/7/2019)**

```
var new data = [
    {ID : 150042379,
    Name : Cake 1234
    Status : 'Not Reservable'
    Code ID : 302},
    {ID : 150042379,
    Name : Cake 1234
    Status : 'Reservable'
    Code ID : 302},
    {ID : 150042379,
    Name : Bread 1236 Ticket
    Status : 'Reservable'
    Code ID : 391},
    {ID : 150053213,
    Name : Bread Basic 8
    Status : 'Reservable'
    Code ID : 201},
    {ID : 150053213,
    Name : Bread Basic 6
    Status : 'Reservable'
    Code ID : 301},
    {ID : 150054121,
    Name : Bread Basic 16
    Status : 'Not Reservable'
    Code ID : 202},
    {ID : 150054121,
    Name : Bread Basic 16
    Status : 'Reservable'
    Code ID : 202},
    {ID : 150057599,
    Name : Bread Riche
    Status : 'Reservable'
    Code ID : 232},
    ]
```

---

Basically we need to check 2 conditions which is ID and Code ID

**For example 1,**

ID and Code ID are the same, and the Status is either Not Reservable or Reservable, we will remove the ID and Code ID that have status of Reservable

**For example 2,**

ID and Code ID are the same, and the Status is either Completed or Reservable, we will remove the ID and Code ID that have status of Completed

**For example 3,**

If 2 IDs are the same, and the Code ID is different, we will display both in the list

So the result that I want

```
var filter_new_data = [
        {ID : 150042379,
        Name : Cake 1234
        Status : 'Not Reservable'
        Code ID : 302},
        {ID : 150042379,
        Name : Bread 1236 Ticket
        Status : 'Reservable'
        Code ID : 391},
        {ID : 150053213,
        Name : Bread Basic 8
        Status : 'Reservable'
        Code ID : 201},
        {ID : 150053213,
        Name : Bread Basic 6
        Status : 'Reservable'
        Code ID : 301},
        {ID : 150054121,
        Name : Bread Basic 16
        Status : 'Not Reservable'
        Code ID : 202},
        {ID : 150057599,
        Name : Bread Riche
        Status : 'Reservable'
        Code ID : 232},
        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using reduce and Object.values to loop through only once and avoiding multiple loops for comparison

1. Loop using reduce
2. Create object with ID as key
3. Check status with ID and update accumulator object
4. Using object.values get the values of filtered Object

```js
var data = [
    {ID : 1,
    Status : 'Completed'},
    {ID : 1,
    Status : 'Fail'},
    {ID : 2,
    Status : 'Fail'},
    {ID : 2,
    Status : 'Completed'},
    {ID : 3,
    Status : 'Fail'},
    {ID : 4,
    Status : 'Completed'},
    {ID : 5,
    Status : 'Completed'},
    ]

var filter_data = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, v) =>{
  if(acc[v.ID]){
acc[v.ID] = acc[v.ID].Status === 'Fail'? acc[v.ID] : v;
  }else{
acc[v.ID] = v
  }
  return acc  
},{}))

console.log(filter_data);
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/qzeYZG?editors=1010

Comment: Hi @Naga Sai A, I just updated the question and is more complex. Could u able to take a look when you free?

Comment: @weikian, as initial question is answered, i think this should be a new question with that complex scenario